# How to make PHP / Cakephp database driven pages that are indexed as static pages by Google

Tags: php, html, cakephp, seo

If you have a database driven website based on PHP / Cakephp , how do you make the database driven pages to look like somesite.html or somesite/ - so that the pages can be indexed by Google

- or so that these pages can be directly linked to

Answer (score 3):

Your question is so lacking in information that it's difficult to know what you're getting at.

First off, I'll make the assumption that you have a domain name. Let's call that **www.yourdomain.com**. You can use .htaccess to rewite that to `http://yourdomain.com` or, conversely to rewrite `http://yourdomain.com` to `http://www.yourdomain.com` using something like this in your.htaccess file, within the mod_rewrite section:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$
```

Now, if it's SEO friendly URLs or slugs you're after, then you'll need to do something along the lines of changing your view method parameter from `$id` to `$url`. You will, of course, need to have a url column on the table you're looking at and within the method you'll need to `findByUrl($url)` rather than `read(null,$id)`. There are many well-documented ways to do this and an intelligent Google search will find them, so I won't spend a couple of hours describing them.

> or so that these pages can be directly
>   linked to

Anything you can see in the address bar of your browser you can link to.

> pages to look like somesite.html or
>   somesite/

The page name does not need to include .html to be indexed. If you don't believe this, google 'BBC' and find a page that ends '.html'

The bottom line is that if it's published and publicly accessible, Google will find and index it.

Answer (score 2):

The web is based around URLs, not `.html` files. If it has a unique URL, it's a unique page that can be requested and indexed. `example.com/products/view/3` and `example.com/products/view/4` are both unique URLs and, as far as Google is concerned, completely separate pages. Whether these pages are lying around on your server's hard disk as `3.html` and `4.html`, are generated dynamically from database content or are hand-typed by trained monkeys on every request is completely irrelevant. If the content comes up when requesting a given URL, it's a page like any other.

Having URLs like `example.com/foo.html` is actually just a very simple and lazy implementation of web servers to map URLs 1:1 to files on the hard disk. This mapping is completely internal to web servers though, the "web" doesn't care about files at all.

If your pages have a URL they can be indexed.
If they're linked to from somewhere, they'll be found automatically.
Automatically generated links on and to automatically generated pages work the same as hand-coded links in static files.

---

In less abstract terms: Don't worry about it, Google will index your Cake pages just fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can easely do that with [URL Rewriting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html)

But that's not the most important part of Google indexation, [it may even be productive cons](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2008/09/dynamic-urls-vs-static-urls.html)!

Answer (score 0):

By following two rules, your data will be easily indexed:

- The data currently show, should correspond to the current URL (e.g. /posts, /posts?dateBefore=2009 etc.)
- All sites you wish to index must be linked from somewhere on the interweb. E.g. from your own site. (Or a sitemap.xml)

File extension in the URL do not matter. Google indexes every site served as text/html (and even images, pdfs...). It just must reach them.